# Swagger and then flask or opposite

Tags: python, flask, swagger

Swagger and then flask or opposite
Hello,

I'm starting a new poroject who need an API.

I 'm going with flask and swagger.

A simple question: should i start by defining the API with swagger and then generate the python code or the opposite.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are solutions for both approaches:

If you end up preferring to define the API first, I would recommend [connexion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion). You define OpenAPI (new name for Swagger) specification files, and then you do Python code accordingly. I would say that this is the best approach as you can guarantee that whatever code you write afterwards will conform to the specification, that you can provide to whoever wants it. Another advantage is not mixing up core concepts of your logic with the API specification.

Otherwise, [flask-restplus](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus) does the trick. This is the most common (but not necessarily better) approach, where you write your Python code and the specification is then generated. This is the approach I usually follow in simple use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For information i finally choose the openapi-generator tool that allow me to generate python server stub on Flask/connexion stack and my client lib for Android on top of okhttp.

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

I was rather satisfied with this choice during my project.

To merge your server stub last version with older one you can dedicated a git branch for raw server stub generation and another one wich you fill with your own code. That way you won't lose your previous version with the code you add to the server stub.